# Django error 'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: python, django

I got this error message if I'm using SQL statement to populate data in dropdown.

Error message

```
'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute 'all'
```

Model.py

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
class FacebookAccount(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    account_description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    facebook_application_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    facebook_application_secret = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ouath_token = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.account_description

@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
class FacebookFanPage(models.Model):
    facebook_account = models.ForeignKey(FacebookAccount)
    fan_page_description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fan_page_id = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    fan_page_access_token = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fan_page_description

class Campaign(models.Model):
    aList = (
        ('1', 'Send replies to inbox messages'),
        ('2', 'Post replies to users comments')
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    campaign_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    autoresponder_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=aList, null=True)
    facebook_account_to_use = models.ForeignKey(FacebookAccount)
    set_auto_reply_for_fan_page = models.ForeignKey(FacebookFanPage)
    message_list_to_use = models.ForeignKey(PredefinedMessage)
    #reply_only_in_this_hourly_interval
    reply_only_for_this_keyword = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

View.py

```
def autoresponder_create(request, template_name='autoresponder/autoresponder_form.html'):
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return redirect('home')
form = AutoresponderForm(request.POST or None)
form.fields["set_auto_reply_for_fan_page"].query = FacebookFanPage.objects.raw('SELECT * '
                                         'FROM fbautoreply_facebookfanpage '
                                         'JOIN fbautoreply_facebookaccount ON fbautoreply_facebookfanpage.facebook_account_id = fbautoreply_facebookaccount.id '
                                         'WHERE fbautoreply_facebookaccount.user_id = %s ', [str(request.user.id)])
if form.is_valid():
    form = form.save(commit=False)
    form.user = request.user
    form.save()
    return redirect('autoresponder_list')
return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})
```

Comment: It probably calls `.all()` on queryset somewhere in framework code. Can you add whole tracelog?

Comment: post your models, this looks like something that can be easily written with the ORM

Comment: @e4c5 please check my updated question.

Answer (score 4):

As the first comment says it seems like you are calling all() on queryset. You dont have to call .all() after executing raw sql queries, if you are assigning that to a variable since that variable already includes all objects fetched by your query.

```
In [6]: t = Team.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM core_team')

In [7]: t
Out[7]: <RawQuerySet: SELECT * FROM core_team>

In [8]: t[0]
Out[8]: <Team: test>
In [9]: [x for x in t ]
Out[9]: [<Team: test>, <Team: team2>, <Team: adminTeam>, <Team: team4>]
```

and if you call t.all()

```
In [11]: t.all()
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-11-2ce0015f044f> in <module>()
    ----> 1 t.all()

    AttributeError: 'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute 'all'

    In [12]:
```

So it seems like you are calling `all()` on after executing a sql raw query. Remove that piece of code and it will be solved.
 You can refer [to this section of django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) if you want to use better ways to execute a sql query.

### Edit

Try changing `form.fields["set_auto_reply_for_fan_page"].query` to `form.fields["set_auto_reply_for_fan_page"].queryset`

Answer (score 0):

you can create view in sql or select query 
then 
you can manupulete this query with raw sql
for example you want to make filter with like contidion.
firs select all joining table with view or select
the query is first query slect all
new query is manuplulated query with raw. 
not: select syntax for postgressql

```
        if request_post:
            if request_post.get('name'):
              name = request_post.get('name')
              name = '%'+name+'%'
              condition = "WHERE account_name like"
              s = '%s'
              new_query = f"""{query}  {condition} {s} """
              queryset=TestOrderDetail.objects.raw(new_query,[name] )
```

Comment: for view you dont need to create model. view can run with cursor connection of course you need to permission to use view. or select *

Comment: by the way after from you have use TestOrderDetail object database table name then join everything

Answer (score -2):

```
form.fields["set_auto_reply_for_fan_page"].choices = [(None, '---'),] + [ (x.id, x.name ,) for x in FacebookFanPage.objects.raw('''select id, name from dual''')]
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion